# What would an interference pattern at relativistic speeds look like?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, quantum-information, time-dilation

What would happen to a dual slit experiment's interference pattern if one observer was moving at relativistic speeds and another wasn't?

For example if an observer performs a double slit experiment on a spaceship with the light traveling perpendicular to the direction of travel, they should see a normal pattern. But special relativity says an observer on the ground will see the light travel at an angle, not perpendicular to the direction of travel. So the interference pattern should be shifted, right?

I think it would be interesting to set up some hypothetical experiments messing around with the following variables:

inputs:

1. The speed/direction and location/time of each observer collapsing the pattern
2. the addition of a delayed choice quantum eraser

Answer (score 2):

Take [this double slit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-slit_experiment#Interference_of_individual_particles) experiment in your space ship, instruments and all.

[image: dingel]

> Buildup of interference pattern from individual particle detections

The "observers" in the double slit are not human, they are the interactions happening at the quantum level in the experiment "electron  of given four momentum scattering off two slits with given distance and width"

The pattern will be the same in all inertial frames.

The distortion induced by a relativistic velocity of the spaceship for humans on earth would be the same as for any photograph on the spaceship, if it could be observed from earth. Nothing to do with the double slit experiment per se.